# python - GroupBy sum as a proportion over start and end date range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am looking at this drone rental dataset on my python discovery journey and was trying to `GroupBy` the **Result** column to show how much each drone made in each month.

I could usually do this if the result was associated for a particular date, but as this is a longer-term rental business I need to work out how much of the result is attributable to each month between the start and end dates.

```
+------+------------------+------------------+--------+
| Drone|     Start        |      End         | Result |
+------+------------------+------------------+--------+
| DR1    16/06/2013 10:30   22/08/2013 07:00    2786  |
| DR1    20/04/2013 23:30   16/06/2013 10:30    7126  |
| DR1    24/01/2013 23:00   20/04/2013 23:30    2964  |
| DR2    01/03/2014 19:00   07/05/2014 18:00    8884  |
| DR2    04/09/2015 09:00   04/11/2015 07:00    7828  |
| DR2    04/10/2013 05:00   24/12/2013 07:00    5700  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

I was able to find the difference in the dates using this:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
df.Start = pd.to_datetime(df.Start)
df.End = pd.to_datetime(df.End)
a = df.loc[0, 'Start']
b = df.loc[0, 'End']
relativedelta(a,b)
```

However the output prints out as such:

> relativedelta(months=-2, days=-5, hours=-20, minutes=-30)

and I can't use this to calculate the cash attributable like I would if the dataset had one date, using a GroupBy

```
df.groupby(['Device', 'Date']).agg(sum)['Result']
```

I would appreciate some help on the correct thought process for approaching a problem like this and what the code would look like.

taking the first example from each drone type,
my expected output would be:

```
+------+-------+-------+---------+
|Drone | Month | Days  |  Result |
+------+-------+-------+---------+
|DR1     June      X       $YY   |
|DR1     July      X       $YY   |
|DR1     August    X       $YY   |
|DR2     March     Y       $ZZ   |
|DR2     April     Y       $ZZ   |
|DR2     May       Y       $ZZ   |
+--------------------------------+
```

**Thanks**

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I added my expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a loopy solution, but I think it does what you want.

```
# Just load the sample data
from io import StringIO
data = 'Drone,Start,End,Result\n' + \
    'DR1,16/06/2013 10:30,22/08/2013 07:00,2786\n' + \
    'DR1,20/04/2013 23:30,16/06/2013 10:30,7126\n' + \
    'DR1,24/01/2013 23:00,20/04/2013 23:30,2964\n' + \
    'DR2,01/03/2014 19:00,07/05/2014 18:00,8884\n' + \
    'DR2,04/09/2015 09:00,04/11/2015 07:00,7828\n' + \
    'DR2,04/10/2013 05:00,24/12/2013 07:00,5700\n'
stream = StringIO(data)

# Actual solution
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv(stream, sep=',', parse_dates=[1, 2])

def get_month_spans(row):
    month_spans = []
    start = row['Start']
    total_delta = (row['End'] - row['Start']).total_seconds()
    while row['End'] > start:
        if start.month != 12:
            end = datetime(year=start.year, month=start.month+1, day=1)
        else:
            end = datetime(year=start.year+1, month=1, day=1)
        if end > row['End']:
            end = row['End']
        delta = (end - start).total_seconds()
        proportional = row['Result'] * (delta / total_delta)
        month_spans.append({'Drone': row['Drone'],
                            'Month': datetime(year=start.year,
                                              month=start.month,
                                              day=1),
                            'Result': proportional,
                            'Days': delta / (24 * 3600)})
        start = end
        print(delta)
    return month_spans

month_spans = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    month_spans += get_month_spans(row)
monthly = pd.DataFrame(month_spans).groupby(['Drone', 'Month']).agg(sum)[['Result', 'Days']]

print(monthly)
```

Which outputs how much each drone made each month along with the number of days:

```
                       Result       Days
Drone Month                             
DR1   2013-01-01   242.633083   7.041667
      2013-02-01   964.789537  28.000000
      2013-03-01  1068.159845  31.000000
      2013-04-01  1953.216797  30.000000
      2013-05-01  3912.726199  31.000000
      2013-06-01  2555.334620  30.000000
      2013-07-01  1291.856653  31.000000
      2013-08-01   887.283266  21.291667
DR2   2013-04-01   459.202454  20.791667
      2013-05-01   684.662577  31.000000
      2013-06-01   662.576687  30.000000
      2013-07-01   684.662577  31.000000
      2013-08-01   684.662577  31.000000
      2013-09-01   662.576687  30.000000
      2013-10-01   684.662577  31.000000
      2013-11-01   662.576687  30.000000
      2013-12-01   514.417178  23.291667
      2014-01-01  1369.726258  28.208333
      2014-02-01  1359.610112  28.000000
      2014-03-01  1505.282624  31.000000
      2014-04-01  1456.725120  30.000000
      2014-05-01  1505.282624  31.000000
      2014-06-01  1456.725120  30.000000
      2014-07-01   230.648144   4.750000
      2015-04-01  7828.000000   1.916667
```

Comment: this is amazing! how easy would printing the number of days spent in each month as another column?

Comment: Not too hard. Just edited my answer to include the number of days (as a float, but you can easily round it if necessary).